# Send custom URL in telegram button bash

Tags: bash, curl, telegram, telegram-bot

I wrote this code with bash for send Messages with telegram bot, now i need send the Message with a custom URL.

This is my actual code:

```
sendTelegram() {
        curl -s \
        -X POST \
        https://api.telegram.org/bot$apiToken/sendMessage \
        -d text="$download" \
        -d chat_id=$userChatId
}
```

How to I can send the Message $download in a URL Button, for example:

[image: URL Button Telegram]

Answer (score 8):

You need to use an inline_keyboard from reply_markup and send a POST request with a JSON content type header:

```
curl -d '{"chat_id":7455490, "text":"pruebax", "reply_markup": {"inline_keyboard": [[{"text":"LaResistencia.co", "url": "http://laresistencia.co"}]]} }' -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X POST https://api.telegram.org/bot$apiToken/sendMessage
```

Check the Telegram bot API inline_keyboard section for more info about the parameters:
https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#inlinekeyboardbutton

[image: Telegram bot bash inline_keyboard]

Answer (score 2):

Please use `reply_markup` like [this payload](https://tg.sean.taipei/payload.php?sendPhoto-8c60e9bd).